# Can't show the full content on UITextView with Highlightr in programmably

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I use `Highlightr` to highlight the code, and following are some codes

```
var highlightr : Highlightr!
let textStorage = CodeAttributedString()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(tvContent)
}
lazy var tvContent:(UITextView) = {
    textStorage.language = "html"
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: view.bounds.size)
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 60, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 10, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 60), textContainer: textContainer)
    return textView
}()
func fromServer() {
    let API_URL = "https://www.google.com"
    Alamofire.request(API_URL)
    .responseJSON { response in
        let data = json.object(forKey: "data")!
        self.tvContent.text = data as? String
    }
}
```

After called the function `fromServer`, I will get the html code of google.com, but the `tvContent` only show some parts of the codes like this.

[show parts of codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA9lr.jpg)

If I remove `Highlightr`, only use UITextView, the `tvContent` can show all codes like this

[show full codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRHRs.jpg)

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the code you posted you never use or even create the `highlightr` object, so I'm pretty sure some important piece of code is missing for us to give you an answer.

Comment: @unixb0y I didn't missing, that's all my codes.

Comment: Where do you use highlightr? Where do you create the object? That code is clearly not included in your question.

Comment: @unixb0y Thanks for helping, but sorry, I am confused, in the demo of official, there's nothing that you said. https://cocoapods.org/pods/Highlightr#codeattributedstring

Comment: Here: They DO create the object: Highlightr() while you don't. At least not in the code that you posted. You just declare the variable but the object is never created. They also do something like this: let highlightedCode = highlightr.highlight(code, as: "swift")  which you don't, at least not here. Without code that is significant to your question we can't do anything. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @unixb0y No, I thought the cocoapods.org/pods/Highlightr#codeattributedstring gives two ways to use Highlightr, and I checked example in their GitHub repository here https://github.com/raspu/Highlightr, there has no what you said.

Comment: @unixb0y I found the issue, and fixed this, thank you all the same.

Answer (score -1):

no need to add height programtically, use constraint and make textview scroll false